# rake gem:install RAILS_ENV=test

Tags: rake

when I am running "rake gem:install RAILS_ENV=test" command it gives me error like

rake aborted!
No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2367:in `raw_load_rakefile'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2007:in`block in load_rakefile'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2058:in `standard_exception_handling'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2006:in`load_rakefile'
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1991:in `run'
c:/Ruby192/bin/rake:31:in`'

what should I do for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is implying that you dont have a Rakefile at the root of where you are executing that command. Without more information about your project structure, it is difficult to say its anything else.